# Commands on minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I am making a garage and I want a set of blocks of the door to be "filled with air" at a time and for some reason these cmnd blocks only have an output when a lever is on the block itself and the chain command blocks aren't working how I'd expect them to (where one after the other gets triggered) please tell me what I need to do.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of your actual command block setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your layout looks similar to this

[image: Example Layout]

What you want to do is make sure that the chain command blocks are set to "Always Active."

And in order to create the animation of opening the garage door a few blocks at a time, you'd want to set up some kind of a wait timer in between filling blocks with air.

Or simply use impulse blocks and repeaters like this

[image: Simple Setup]

Comment: YoshinoBHL my layout kind of looks like your first photo but instead it's a impulse block and the chain blocks well like u had it

Comment: Alright, well in any case you could just set up your layout like the second image, the time interval can be adjusted with different number of repeaters, 1 second is equivalent to 5 fully extended repeaters. This is a lot easier than setting up a chain of commands. And in order to start the opening animation simply activate the first command block in the line using any kind of redstone power

Comment: YoshinoBHL also do you know any way i can use command blocks to make a working sec. Camera

Comment: By "Sec. Camera" you mean security camera? The basic idea is to turn the player who have selected a camera into spectator mode, then tp them to the camera location, you'd want to keep teleporting them using a repeat block because you'd want them to be stuck at the camera's physical location. As for how to exit the camera... this depends on you, usually people just do a tellraw command and output a "Exit Camera" in chat, so that when you click on it, it will execute a command that teleports the player back to the camera room and change back the gamemode

Comment: Thx (now my fnaf based building can be complete

Comment: Umm this can be closed, how do i vote to remove?